# How do I access call log for android?

Tags: android

I would like to receive the call log.  For example the number of calls made by the user, number of minutes called, etc.

How do I achieve this in android?

Comment: may be this is solution for U http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html

Comment: I remeber it being content resolver, however i have no idea how to start the thing.

Answer (score 74):

This is for accessing phone call history:

As of Jellybean (4.1) you need the following permission:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />`

**Code:**

```
 Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
 Cursor c = managedQuery(allCalls, null, null, null, null);

String num= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));// for  number
String name= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));// for name
String duration = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));// for duration
int type = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));// for call type, Incoming or out going.
```

Comment: Don't forget to enable this permission:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />

this is the method to get the call log:

Comment: I do not know that but theoretically I can say that all the messages are stored in same database. So yes it can access all the messages of device regardless of dual sim or single sim. Check this code and let me know if its not working with dual sim. I will do some R&D and provide you a code for that.

Comment: get name will always return null, be careful

Comment: @Abhinav Singh Maurya can you help me to get call log photo_uri from call logs because I not able to get photo_uri from call log

Comment: @Sagar2869767 You can check it by using CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_URI and can get photo id by CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_ID. Check it and let me know if it is working or not. Also it can return null if no image is set on contact.

Comment: @Abhinav Singh Maurya thanks for suggestion I have tried for this solution .It works above M/21 API level. One more issue is their on some CACHED_NAME and  CACHED_PHOTO_ID after contact update wont reflect immediately. Is their any other way to get name and photo instead of cache name/photo.It should be faster

Comment: `managedQuery()` is now deprecated. Use `getContentResolver().query()` instead.

Comment: managedQuery() deprecated use this instead 
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");

Comment: Note that for `Calls.NUMBER` , you might see weird phone number (example : "-2") in case it's a private number (AKA unknown phone number). This occurs for me on Galaxy S7, but never on other phones. There is a way to overcome this, by also checking out `Calls.NUMBER_PRESENTATION`, as I've written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353517/878126

Answer (score 70):

This is method used to get the Call log. Just put this method in you class and get the List of the Call Log.

[Check out this](http://android2011dev.blogspot.in/2011/08/get-android-phone-call-historylog.html)

```
private String getCallDetails() {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
        int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
        int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
        int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
        sb.append("Call Details :");
        while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
            String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
            String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
            Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
            String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
            String dir = null;
            int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
            switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
            }
            sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
                    + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
                    + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
            sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
        }
        managedCursor.close();
        return sb.toString();

    }
```

the output looks

[image]

Comment: I am geting error at managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

Comment: I used contentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);

Comment: @Dwivedi Ji - It is a bit an old post - Your method works but it is taking at least 10 seconds to load all my call logs.

Comment: @TheDevMan, sorry for your inconvenience ,Yes you are right, I will update my answer soon,

Comment: How we identify on which SIM call is received ? Ex. In dual SIM mobile i received call on SIM1 so i want information that Call is on SIM1.

Comment: @Dwivedi Ji  How to get call log image from logs ,above M and below M. please help

Comment: deprecated, please see the @ingyesid answer!

Answer (score 54):

use this method from everywhere with a context

```
private static String getCallDetails(Context context) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
    int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);       
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = cursor.getString(number);
        String callType = cursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = cursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = cursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            dir = "INCOMING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "MISSED";
            break;
        }
        stringBuffer.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
                + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
                + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        stringBuffer.append("\n----------------------------------");
    }
    cursor.close();
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Since managedQuery is now deprecated so this answer is most relevant.

Answer (score 16):

This post is a little bit old, but here is another easy solution for getting data related to `Call` logs content provider in Android:

Use this lib: https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers

Get all calls:

```
CallsProvider callsProvider = new CallsProvider(context);
List<Call> calls = callsProvider.getCalls().getList();
```

Each **Call** has all fields, so you can get any info you need:
*callDate, duration, number, type(INCOMING, OUTGOING, MISSED), isRead, ...*

It works with `List` or `Cursor` and there is a sample app to see how it looks and works.

In fact, there is a support for all Android content providers like: *Contacts, SMS, Calendar, ...*
Full doc with all options: https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers/wiki/Android-providers

Hope it also helped :)

Comment: Hey, I checked your solution, it is good. The only problem that I am facing is that how to add the dependency in my eclipse project?

Comment: @aradhna the library is using gradle and was built from Android Studio. I think, you will need to modify it a little to make it run on Eclipse

Comment: @sromku Sir I have seen the Library and read wikis but didn't get how I can add this library to my android project. Can you please help me explaining the process that how can I add this library into my android project. Will be very thank full.

Comment: Where exactly I should add ```compile 'me.everything:providers-android:1.0.1'``` this line in my project and is there any need to download something?

Answer (score 9):

in My project i am getting error int htc device.now this code is universal.
I think this is help for you.

```
    public class CustomContentObserver extends ContentObserver {        
    public CustomContentObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        System.out.println("Content obser");
    }     

    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
         super.onChange(selfChange);
         String lastCallnumber;

         currentDate = sdfcur.format(calender.getTime());
         System.out.println("Content obser onChange()");
         Log.d("PhoneService", "custom StringsContentObserver.onChange( " + selfChange + ")");
        //if(!callFlag){                   
         String[] projection = new String[]{CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                    CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                    CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
                    CallLog.Calls._ID};

            Cursor c;   
            c=mContext.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, CallLog.Calls._ID + " DESC");
            if(c.getCount()!=0){
                c.moveToFirst();
                 lastCallnumber = c.getString(0);
                 String type=c.getString(1);
                 String duration=c.getString(2);
                 String name=c.getString(3);
                 String id=c.getString(4);
                 System.out.println("CALLLLing:"+lastCallnumber+"Type:"+type);

                 Database db=new Database(mContext);
                 Cursor cur =db.getFirstRecord(lastCallnumber);
                 final String endCall=lastCallnumber;
                 //checking incoming/outgoing call
                 if(type.equals("3")){
                    //missed call
                    }else if(type.equals("1")){
                    //incoming call

                 }else if(type.equals("2")){
                    //outgoing call
                 }                  

            }
            c.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

**To get Incoming,Outgoing and Missed Call history , hope this code will help u:)**

Call this code on your background thread.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

String[] projection = new String[] {
    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
    CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
    CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
    CallLog.Calls.DATE,
    CallLog.Calls.DURATION
};

sb.append("Call Details :");

// String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";

Cursor managedCursor =  getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
    String name = managedCursor.getString(0); //name
    String number = managedCursor.getString(1); // number
    String type = managedCursor.getString(2); // type 
    String date = managedCursor.getString(3); // time 
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") 
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
    String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(Long.parseLong(date)));

    String duration = managedCursor.getString(4); // duration

    String dir = null;
    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(type);
    switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            dir = "INCOMING";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "MISSED";
            break;
    }

sb.append("\nPhone Name :-- "+name+"  Number:--- " + number + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + dateString + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + duration);
sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
```

Answer (score 4):

Before considering making Read Call Log or Read SMS permissions a part of your application I strongly advise you to have a look at this policy of Google Play Market: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303?hl=en

Those permissions are very sensitive and you will have to prove that your application needs them. But even if it really needs them Google Play Support team may easily reject your request without proper explanations.

This is what happened to me. After providing all the needed information along with the Demonstration video of my application it was rejected with the explanation that my **"account is not authorized to provide a certain use case solution in my application"** (the list of use cases they may consider as an exception is listed on that Policy page). No link to any policy statement was provided to explain what it all means. Basically they just judged my app as not to go without proper explanation.

I wish you good luck of cause with your applications guys but be careful.

Answer (score 2):

**To get Only Incoming Call history , the beneath code will help u:)**

```
private void getCallDetailsAgil() {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Details :");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);


        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
                sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
                miss_cal.setText(sb);
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }
    }

    managedCursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use Below code:**

```
private void getCallDeatils() {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = getActivity().managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);

    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    stringBuffer.append("Call Deatils");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String reportDate = df.format(callDayTime);
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";

                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;

        }
        stringBuffer.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " +callDate + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        stringBuffer.append("\n----------------------------------");

        logs.add(new LogClass(phNumber,dir,reportDate,callDuration));




    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If we use Kotlin it is shorter. Example of class which responds for provide call logs:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.provider.CallLog.Calls.*

class CallsLoader {

    fun getCallLogs(context: Context): List<List<String?>> {
        val c = context.applicationContext
        val projection = arrayOf(CACHED_NAME, NUMBER, TYPE, DATE, DURATION)

        val cursor = c.contentResolver.query(
             CONTENT_URI,
             projection,
             null,
             null,
             null,
             null
          )

         return cursorToMatrix(cursor)
     }

    private fun cursorToMatrix(cursor: Cursor?): List<List<String?>> {
        val matrix = mutableListOf<List<String?>>()
        cursor?.use {
             while (it.moveToNext()) {
                 val list = listOf(
                    it.getStringFromColumn(CACHED_NAME),
                    it.getStringFromColumn(NUMBER),
                    it.getStringFromColumn(TYPE),
                    it.getStringFromColumn(DATE),
                    it.getStringFromColumn(DURATION)
                 )

                 matrix.add(list.toList())
             }
          }

          return matrix
      }

     private fun Cursor.getStringFromColumn(columnName: String) =
        getString(getColumnIndex(columnName))
}
```

We can also convert cursor to map:

```
fun getCallLogs(context: Context): Map<String, Array<String?>> {
    val c = context.applicationContext
    val projection = arrayOf(CACHED_NAME, NUMBER, TYPE, DATE, DURATION)

    val cursor = c.contentResolver.query(
        CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    )

    return cursorToMap(cursor)
}

private fun cursorToMap(cursor: Cursor?): Map<String, Array<String?>> {
    val arraySize = cursor?.count ?: 0
    val map = mapOf(
        CACHED_NAME to Array<String?>(arraySize) { "" },
        NUMBER to Array<String?>(arraySize) { "" },
        TYPE to Array<String?>(arraySize) { "" },
        DATE to Array<String?>(arraySize) { "" },
        DURATION to Array<String?>(arraySize) { "" }
    )

    cursor?.use {
        for (i in 0 until arraySize) {
            it.moveToNext()

            map[CACHED_NAME]?.set(i, it.getStringFromColumn(CACHED_NAME))
            map[NUMBER]?.set(i, it.getStringFromColumn(NUMBER))
            map[TYPE]?.set(i, it.getStringFromColumn(TYPE))
            map[DATE]?.set(i, it.getStringFromColumn(DATE))
            map[DURATION]?.set(i, it.getStringFromColumn(DURATION))
        }
    }

    return map
}
```