# How are call types (Incoming/Outgoing/Missed) stored in Android Call Log?

Tags: android

This may be a silly question, I'm a bit of a noob. I was reading this post: [How do I access call log for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android)

and in the answer at the bottom of the code they have this line:

```
int type = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));// for call type, Incoming or out going
```

I'm a little confused as to how the call type is stored, is it as a string or as an integer?
The line of code shown makes me think its saved as a number, but in string format. Can anyone explain this to me?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The type is stored as integer. This is how I get a list of new missed calls:

```
cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"), null, "type = 3 AND new = 1", null, "date DESC");
```

Of course using the CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE, INCOMING_TYPE and OUTGOING_TYPE constant would be better.

Answer (score 5):

Here `CallLog.Calls.TYPE` gives you the field name in the database to fetch the info of call type which contains integer values to save the type of calls,though it might be a text field.

1 for incoming type

2 for missed type

3 for outgoing type

You just need to use them like `android.provider.CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE`,
`android.provider.CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE` and `android.provider.CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE` only.

Answer (score 3):

Referring to the: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#INCOMING_TYPE

`1` for incoming type

`2` for outgoing type

`3` for missed type

Answer (score 3):

use this method

```
private static String getCallDetails(Context context) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
    int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);       
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = cursor.getString(number);
        String callType = cursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = cursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = cursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;
        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            dir = "INCOMING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "MISSED";
            break;
        }
        stringBuffer.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
                + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
                + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
        stringBuffer.append("\n----------------------------------");
    }
    cursor.close();
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: How we can get the number on which Callogs is received? ex. I have dual sim mobile so i want to know that +987654123 is Incoming call on SIM1 and +369258147 Missed call on SIM2? Please help me if you have solution of it.

Answer (score 0):

This also worked for me try this.

`String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + "=1 "+" OR "+ CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + "=3";`