# Incoming call type in android

Tags: android

I want to detect incoming call type in my application.can we know incoming call is domestic or international in android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835876/how-are-call-types-incoming-outgoing-missed-stored-in-android-call-log

Comment: http://blog.wangling.me/2009/08/why-it-is-impossible-to-intercept-incoming-calls-on-android/

Comment: I want to know weather call is domestioc or international?

Comment: basicly, its impossible.

Comment: cant we use the country code to acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

hey this is all about detect incoming or outgoing or missed call type in an android application. 
try this code this will definetly help you. i will answer you further on differentiating between an international and domestic call.

```
Cursor cur = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {
            CallLog.Calls._ID, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
            CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.DATE  },
            null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
int typeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);

                    // Type of call retrieved from the cursor.
                    int type = cursor.getInt(typeIndex);

                    switch (type) {
                    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
```

**//write your code here**

```
                        break;
                    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                        break;
                    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and get the incoming phone number and get the first couple digits. For example:+38977xxxxxx, where +389 is number from foreign country