# How to show only missed calls from call log android

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

Please guide me how to apply condition on call type only missed call number add in list . And secondly hot to sort this list by date wise and how to delete seleted items from list.

public void getlog()

```
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int name = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)

    int numberOfRows = managedCursor.getCount();
    if (numberOfRows > 0) {
        if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                    String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
                    String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
                    String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
                    Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
                    String namec = managedCursor.getString(name);

                    if (namec == null) {
                        namec = "Unknown";
                    }

                    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hm.put("listview_title", namec);
                    hm.put("listview_number", phNumber);
                    hm.put("listview_date", String.valueOf(callDayTime));
                    hm.put("listview_image", image);
                if(type == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE){ aList.add(hm);

            }
            while (managedCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        String[] from = {"listview_image", "listview_title", "listview_number", "listview_date"};
        int[] to = {R.id.listview_image, R.id.listview_item_title, R.id.listview_item_number, R.id.listview_item_time};
        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.custmlv, from, to);
        androidListView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
        androidListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
        managedCursor.close();
         Collections.reverse(aList);
    }

}
```

Comment: Check the CallLog.Calls.TYPE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835876/how-are-call-types-incoming-outgoing-missed-stored-in-android-call-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your conditional statement with below code

```
    String dir = null;
    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);


    switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            dir = "INCOMING";
            sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- " + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
            sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
            miss_cal.setText(sb);
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "MISSED";
            break;
    }
```

The problem with your code is you are testing condition with variable '**type**'   This is your column name rather column value. You should have checked callType, as you are also getting call type. Convert callType String to in and then campare as you comparing with CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE: 
 Hope that helps you.

Comment: @UsmanArshad if that helped you please don't forget to accept and mark this answer as useful :)

Comment: please guide me how to remove list items by long click listener.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
    switch (dircode) 
    {
    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
    break;
    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
    break;
    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
          HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
           hm.put("listview_title", namec);
           hm.put("listview_number", phNumber);
           hm.put("listview_date", String.valueOf(callDayTime));
           hm.put("listview_image", image);
           aList.add(hm);

            break;
     }
```