# Android: How to open Call Log (missed-outgoing-incoming call view)?

Tags: android, logging, phone-call

I am able to open the Call Log through the following lines:

```
Intent showCallLog = new Intent();
        showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        showCallLog.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
        showCallLog.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(showCallLog);
```

However I would like to open only a single view of the CallLog (for example Missed Call)

I tried to add

```
showCallLog.putExtra(CallLog.Calls.TYPE,CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE);
```

but it doesn't change anything!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can open it that way (at least, not on all devices), but you can get the call log like this (you have to show it to the user yourself. Check the link bellow). This is the save way, to make sure that the user is going to see exactly what you want, but you have to create it yourself.
Check this thread for further help: [How do I access call log for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android) . Hope this helps.