# Getting phone call logs in monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

How do I get access to the phone call log via c# in monoTouch? I want to be able to help my legal clients bill for calls received or made. So I need to be able to see the details of a call and institute a billing procedure soon after the call is made.

Any sample code out there? THANKS!

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  Apple doesn't expose any APIs for accessing the Phone logs.

Answer (score 1):

As you can't access the phone logs through the SDK, one thing you could do is recreate the iOS phone app's functionality in your app as well, and have your client use that instead.

```
1) Your app would show contacts
2) Tap a contact to call
3) (Your app logs the contact and call time)
4) Pass the call off to the actual phone app
```

For this client project though, it might be easier to have them buy Android phones, and use Xamarin.Android.  [How do I access call log for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android)