# android call log retrieval limitation?

Tags: android, call, calllog

I have tried to retrive call log using method of content uri as suggested on this link:
[How do I access call log for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android)
[Link for suggested retrieval of call log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android)

But I am having one problem.
I only get limited number of call Log entries like around 500 only...
Why am I not getting all entries of the call logs?

Answer (score 1):

500 entries is an android system limitation.
everything beyond that number is a custom database.

Comment: you have to access the custom databases, but you cannot. you can only create your own implementation to store future call logs, but you cannot retrieve more than 500 from android db.