# How to get call log history for individual contacts programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

How to get call log history for individual contacts, incoming calls and out going calls separately and call log history for particular date in calender programmatically?

Comment: please reply @rtruzk

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access call log for android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android)

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to my answer provided on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android/6786962#6786962) post for accessing call log history. You can get the outgoing and incoming call logs and use them accordingly

Comment: how to get individual number log history like how many times we got call from particular number since last 10 days, total call duration of a single number for different calling times etc.

Comment: That is your own calculation. You can get all the numbers and duration. From that bunch you have to extract data of particular number and duration. Its a totally logic based coding.