# Read calls made on a particular date only from android call logs

Tags: android, performance

I am writing an app which needs runs everyday and should read the last days(previous day) call logs.

I wrote the code to fetch all the call logs with help from
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android) but how can I optimize it to read only yesterdays call log from DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer myself

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderID, Bundle args) {
        Log.d("CallLogs", "onCreateLoader() >> loaderID : " + loaderID);

        switch (loaderID) {
            case URL_LOADER:

                String mSelectionClause = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE+ " >= ?";
                    String[]mSelectionArgs = {createDate()};
                // Returns a new CursorLoader
                return new CursorLoader(
                        mContext,   // Parent activity context
                        CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,        // Table to query
                        null,     // Projection to return
                        mSelectionClause,            // No selection clause
                        mSelectionArgs,            // No selection arguments
                        CallLog.Calls.DATE + " desc"             // Default sort order
                );
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }


 public  String createDate()
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

        return String.valueOf(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    }
```