# Exception on getting cal log from android device

Tags: android

I was trying to get call logs from android device by using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android).

```
 Cursor c = managedQuery(allCalls, null, null, null, null);

        String num= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));// for  number
        String name= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));// for name
        String duration = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));// for duration
        int type = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));//
```

and getting an exception as:
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 500

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: can you check the value of `cursor.getColumnCount()`?

Comment: also provide what `allCalls` is and the code for the method managedQuery

Comment: Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"); managedQuery is a deprecated method in  Activity.class

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

Pass new `String[]{"*"}` as a projection instead of `null`.

```
Cursor c = managedQuery(allCalls, new String[]{"*"}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: It shows  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column *

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after trying this code

```
 Cursor c = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);



        int durationIndex = c.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

        String duration="";
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
           duration = c.getString(durationIndex);
        }
```

number and name is not required for me, but we can get that too using the same way.