# How to read missed call numbers android

Tags: android

I want to run a background service, which reads the missed call numbers and stores in some database, is it possible to read call log particularly missed calls in android? If possible please let me know, any tutorial will be helpful to me.

Comment: can you share the code or anything you have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [`CallLog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.html) content provider with which you can access the, well, call-log from a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

There are already examples on Stackoverflow how to access the log and which permissions your application requires, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android).