# How to get call log with specific contact

Tags: android, logging, cursor, call, calllog

i'm building an application that works wih call log, my questien is how can I get call log for specific contact?,

i saw this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14050724/4427731

But, if I want to use this answer I'll have to go through all the calllog, which takes a long time and ineffective, there is any other way to do that?