# How to get Dialed number in my Application Without Permission

Tags: android, android-dialer

I want to get Dialed Number in my application but without any Manifest Permission tag. I know how to do it with permission,

Is there a way to do this without Manifest Permission tag?

Comment: There's no way, if such ways are there, why permission module is introduced?

Comment: In simple words, **NO**. There is no way you can do this without requesting for permission. Its is designed to be like this only. If it was possible, any app would be able to get user call log and contacts, which is a huge security flaw.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, there's no way to get dialed numbers without taking permission from the user. And, this is the answer to your question.

Google is much concerned about the privacy of their users, so you cannot fetch personal informations of user without their own permission.

But still if you want to do that then you might have wanted to create your own OS.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is right you don't do it without permission.
You can do it with permission only by way describe in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android/14050724) link.

Although in new policies of google you can't request for permission of call logs and SMS if [your app doesn’t really require these permissions](https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-sms-call-log-permissions-now-what-9b8226de7827).

So, I think there is no way to do it.

Comment: *Although in new policies of google you can't request for permission of call logs and SMS if your app doesn’t really require these permissions.* Posting this is redundant, because OP does want to fetch dialed number, *But without permission.* So this line seems to be out of topic altogether.

Comment: I think you are talking it wrong @Zlytherin because dialed number mean he need to get from call logs. The second thing is he can't to without permission.

Comment: The link states that you should not ask for permission if your app doesn't really require these permission. But the case here is exactly opposite to it. He need the permission but he don't want to take permission.

Comment: My friend I generally answer for both the Questioner and general readers. So, we can help others as well. I am sorry If you feel it's not suitable.